# Mobile Broadband cannot connect Ubuntu 16.04 with EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A Lenovo Thinkpad X260 notebook

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, modem-manager

I  have a little problem installing a modem in my new Lenovo Thinkpad X260 notebook. The model of the modem is Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A and OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

At the login screen into Ubuntu, I had an popup to enter the PIN so I have disabled PIN for the SIM card in a mobile phone. This is an absolutely fresh installation of Ubuntu downloaded and installed May 2017 with absolutely nothing else installed, only tried to run the modem. The output is

> Mobile Broadband - not enabled in Network Manager.

I have tried creating a new connection in **Settings > Network > Mobile broadband**, but after creating it, it's not possible to click on it any more, it doesn't show up anywhere. When I click network manager I can create a new network via **Edit Connections**, but again, this newly created connection isn't listed anywhere. I also tried a software called Sakis3G but with no luck. I don't want to switch to Windows just because of this.

---

#### Things I found somewhere & tried:

1. First thing I did was to put the sim card into the mobile phone. Internet works there, and I've disabled PIN on the card. Moreover, I have tested the modem in Windows 7 and 10 and in both, it works.
2. I have created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-sierra.rules` with following content:

   ```
   ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end" 
   SUBSYSTEM!="usb|drivers", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"    

   # load qmi_wwan module
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
   ATTR{idVendor}=="1199", ATTR{idProduct}=="9079", \
   RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qmi_wwan"

   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
   ATTR{idVendor}=="1199", ATTR{idProduct}=="9079", \
   ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="1"

   # add the new id in the qmi_wwan driver
   SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
   ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb/drivers/qmi_wwan", \
   ATTR{new_id}="1199 9079"

   # load qcserial module
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
   ATTR{idVendor}=="1199", ATTR{idProduct}=="9079", \
   RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qcserial"

   # add the new id in the qcserial driver
   SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
   ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb-serial/drivers/qcserial", \
   ATTR{new_id}="1199 9079"

   LABEL="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
   ```
3. I added at the bottom of a file `/etc/modules`

   ```
   usbserial vendor=0x1199 product=0x9079
   ```
4. I created `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1199:9079` with contents:

   ```
   DefaultVendor= 0x1199
   DefaultProduct=0x9079
   TargetVendor= 0x1199 
   TargetProduct= 0x9079
   CheckSuccess=20 
   MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000606f5
   0402527000000000000000000000"
   ```

---

#### Output of some commands:

```
$ lsb_release -a; uname -a; lsusb
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
Linux arachis 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0706 Acer, Inc
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path Device Class Description
==========================================================
                                system 20F5S2VA00 (LENOVO_MT_20F5_BU_Thi
/0 bus 20F5S2VA00
/0/3 memory 64KiB L1 cache
/0/4 memory 64KiB L1 cache
/0/5 memory 512KiB L2 cache
/0/6 memory 3MiB L3 cache
/0/7 processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @
/0/8 memory 8GiB System Memory
/0/8/0 memory 8GiB SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz
/0/8/1 memory [empty]
/0/8/2 memory [empty]
/0/8/3 memory [empty]
/0/e memory 128KiB BIOS
/0/100 bridge Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registe
/0/100/2 display Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
/0/100/14 bus Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0 usb1 bus xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/3 communication Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm S
/0/100/14/0/8 multimedia Integrated Camera
/0/100/14/0/9 generic Fingerprint Reader
/0/100/14/1 usb2 bus xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2 generic Intel Corporation
/0/100/16 communication Intel Corporation
/0/100/17 storage Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c bridge Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0 generic Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
/0/100/1c.2 bridge Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.2/0 wlp4s0 network Wireless 8260
/0/100/1f bridge Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.2 memory Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3 multimedia Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4 bus Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.6 enp0s31f6 network Ethernet Connection I219-V
/0/0 scsi1 storage
/0/0/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 256GB SanDisk SD8TB8U2
/0/0/0.0.0/1 /dev/sda1 volume 231GiB EXT4 volume
/0/0/0.0.0/2 /dev/sda2 volume 7618MiB Extended partition
/0/0/0.0.0/2/5 /dev/sda5 volume 7618MiB Linux swap / Solaris part
/1 power 45N1773
/2 power 45N1775
/3 wwp0s20f0u3i12 network Ethernet interface
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:a4:71:ef:42:6e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=21.302800.0 ip=192.168.0.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:126 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: c8:5b:76:4b:4d:2e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:123 memory:f1200000-f121ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wwp0s20f0u3i12
       serial: 36:33:6f:65:e0:32
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C communication
 *-usb:0
       description: Communication device
       product: Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
       vendor: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       version: 0.06
       serial: LF63560757041014
       capabilities: usb-2.10
       configuration: driver=cdc_mbim maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-communication
       description: Communication controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 16
       bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:f124b000-f124bfff
```

---

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libmbim
libmbim-glib-dev:amd64 install
libmbim-glib-doc install
libmbim-glib0:amd64 install
libmbim-glib4:amd64 install
libmbim-glib4-dbg install
libmbim-proxy install
libmbim-utils install
```

---

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libqmi
libqmi-glib-dev:amd64 install
libqmi-glib-doc install
libqmi-glib0:amd64 install
libqmi-glib0-dbg install
libqmi-glib1:amd64 install
libqmi-glib1-dbg install
libqmi-proxy install
libqmi-utils install
```

---

```
$ uname -r
4.8.0-36-generic

$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

---

```
$ usb-devices
T: Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.08
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.8.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
S: Product=xHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1199 ProdID=9079 Rev=00.06
S: Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S: Product=Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
S: SerialNumber=LF63560757041014
C: #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=qcserial
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: c: invalid number
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=0e Prot=00 Driver=cdc_mbim
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: d: invalid number
I: If#= 0 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=02 Driver=cdc_mbim
I: If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial
I: If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qcserial

T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=07 Cnt=02 Dev#= 4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=5986 ProdID=0706 Rev=00.12
S: Manufacturer=SunplusIT Inc
S: Product=Integrated Camera
C: #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=03 Dev#= 5 Spd=12 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=11 Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=138a ProdID=0017 Rev=00.78
S: SerialNumber=af9c0fff2423
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

T: Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D: Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.08
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.8.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
S: Product=xHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

---

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | tail -15
May 24 21:01:49 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
May 24 21:01:49 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
May 24 21:01:51 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <info> Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0': not supported by any plugin
May 24 21:01:51 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <info> Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <info> Creating modem with plugin 'Gobi' and '5' ports
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> Could not grab port (usbmisc/cdc-wdm0): 'Cannot add port 'usbmisc/cdc-wdm0', unsupported'
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB1): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB1', unhandled serial type'
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <info> Modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3' successfully created
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <warn> Modem couldn't be initialized: Couldn't check unlock status: SIM failure
May 24 21:02:05 arachis ModemManager[2749]: <info> Modem: state changed (unknown -> failed)
May 24 21:02:05 arachis NetworkManager[887]: <info> [1495652525.5797] manager: (ttyUSB2): new Broadband device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
May 24 21:02:05 arachis NetworkManager[887]: <info> [1495652525.5813] device (ttyUSB2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
May 24 21:02:05 arachis NetworkManager[887]: <info> [1495652525.5822] device (ttyUSB2): modem state 'failed'
May 24 21:02:05 arachis NetworkManager[887]: <warn> [1495652525.5839] (ttyUSB2): failed to retrieve SIM object: No SIM object available
```

Comment: Solved using this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/763238/sierra-wireless-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

I had also a similar issue, the only difference is that I have a Fibocom Cat6 L830-EB 4G LTE.

I don't know if this might help you, but i fixed the issue with downloading the ,,Modem Manager GUI'' from the Ubuntu Software center.

I have a Thinkpad T480 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I hope this may help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue using linux mint 18.2 (Ubuntu 16.04)

1) add 16.10 sources to apt

2) Install modemmanager-1.6.0 from source and its dependencies

```
# cd /usr/src
# apt-get source modemmanager {libmbim libqmi}
# apt-get build-dep {*}
# cd {*} ; dpkg-buildpackage
```

3) Should work now :-)

```
diff 170726.new 170726.orig 
381c381
< ii  gir1.2-modemmanager-1.0:amd64                               1.6.0-1                                                 amd64        GObject introspection data for modemmanager
---
> ii  gir1.2-modemmanager-1.0:amd64                               1.4.12-1ubuntu1                                         amd64        GObject introspection data for modemmanager
1126,1129c1126,1127
< ii  libmbim-glib-dev:amd64                                      1.14.0-1                                                amd64        Header files for adding MBIM support to applications that use glib
< ii  libmbim-glib4:amd64                                         1.14.0-1                                                amd64        Support library to use the MBIM protocol
< ii  libmbim-proxy                                               1.14.0-1                                                amd64        Proxy to communicate with MBIM ports
< ii  libmbim-utils                                               1.14.0-1                                                amd64        Utilities to use the MBIM protocol from the command line
---
> ii  libmbim-glib4:amd64                                         1.12.2-2ubuntu1                                         amd64        Support library to use the MBIM protocol
> ii  libmbim-proxy                                               1.12.2-2ubuntu1                                         amd64        Proxy to communicate with MBIM ports
1147,1149c1145,1146
< ii  libmm-glib-dev:amd64                                        1.6.0-1                                                 amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - library development files
< ii  libmm-glib-doc                                              1.6.0-1                                                 all          D-Bus service for managing modems - library documentation
< ii  libmm-glib0:amd64                                           1.6.0-1                                                 amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - shared libraries
---
> ii  libmm-glib-dev:amd64                                        1.4.12-1ubuntu1                                         amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - library development files
> ii  libmm-glib0:amd64                                           1.4.12-1ubuntu1                                         amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - shared libraries
1372,1373d1368
< ii  libqmi-glib-dev:amd64                                       1.16.0-1                                                amd64        Header files for adding QMI support to applications that use glib
< ii  libqmi-glib-doc                                             1.16.0-1                                                all          API documentation for libqmi-glib
1375,1377c1370,1371
< ii  libqmi-glib5:amd64                                          1.16.0-1                                                amd64        Support library to use the Qualcomm MSM Interface (QMI) protocol
< ii  libqmi-proxy                                                1.16.0-1                                                amd64        Proxy to communicate with QMI ports
< ii  libqmi-utils                                                1.16.0-1                                                amd64        Utilities to use the QMI protocol from the command line
---
> ii  libqmi-proxy                                                1.12.6-1                                                amd64        Proxy to communicate with QMI ports
> ii  libqmi-utils                                                1.12.6-1                                                amd64        Utilities to use the QMI protocol from the command line
1876,1878c1870,1871
< ii  modemmanager                                                1.6.0-1                                                 amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems
< ii  modemmanager-dev:amd64                                      1.6.0-1                                                 amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - development files
< ii  modemmanager-doc                                            1.6.0-1                                                 all          D-Bus service for managing modems - documentation files
---
> ii  modemmanager                                                1.4.12-1ubuntu1                                         amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems
> ii  modemmanager-dev:amd64                                      1.4.12-1ubuntu1                                         amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems - development files
```